# What is the point of using the double logical not "!!" operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I quite regularly see some code like this:

```
const a = !!b && b.c === true;
```

I suppose the idea is to not have the a variable nullable, but in that case what is the difference with this code:

```
const a = b?.c === true
```

Is there a fundamental difference in between the two?

Comment: The first one works before [TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: The canonical question is *[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/)*. With 50 answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is more a JavaScript side of a problem...

The `&&` operator returns the first falsy value, so `0`, `''`, `undefined`, `NaN` or `null` would be the value of `const a`. If you want a boolean then the `!!` syntax is the most common way to ensure it being a Boolean.

If I'm not completely wrong on this the optional chaining (`?.`) just stops the execution on undefined or null values and returns undefined.

Comment: Arguably `!!(b && b.c)` might be nicer…

Comment: bug potential as this would change the program logic from `b.c` needs to be equal to `true` to `b.c` needs to be truthy

Comment: True, though seeing this code I would assume the author is simply hyper vigilant about types instead of being more… dynamic Javascript-y about them. The difference between `true` and *truthy* probably wouldn't make a difference. Of course, if it does, then yes, you should rather use the explicit comparison.

Comment: In this case, `a` will always be the literal `true` or `false`, not "0, '', undefined, NaN or null "

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is such that `b`, if it exists (isn't undefined or null), will be an object, then no, there isn't any difference between those two.

The largest reason why you probably see `someVar && someVar.someProp` (or `!!someVar && someVar.someProp`) and variations is that optional chaining is *pretty new* syntax. It will only exist in recently-updated codebases (running TypeScript 3.7 or above).

But if a variable may be falsy, but is not necessarily an object - for example, if it's 0, NaN, false, or the empty string, then those constructs are *not* equivalent. Optional chaining with `?.` will short-circuit to `undefined` *only* if expression to the left of the `?.` is `null` or `undefined`. Other falsy values will continue to have their properties be evaluated as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions have the same result.

---

The crucial difference is: compatibility

In pure JavaScript, the `?.` operator is really recent: See the *[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility)* chart on [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs). My current browser, for example, (today is 2020-03-11, and my Linux system is running Firefox 73) does not support the `b?.c` syntax.

The `b?.c === true` version could simply not be written before [ES2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#11th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2020) and will not work as is on your client's browser if he/she hasn't updated to recent builds to this day: "recent" would mean "bleeding edge"...

As [mentioned by jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631834/what-is-the-point-of-using-double-logical-not-operator-in-javascript#comment107268527_60631834) in his comment, the `?.` operator is also available through transpiled languages ([TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript), [CoffeeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), etc.), with various dates of support.